# How could I have my discord bot send the message in the channel that the slash-command was used in? (Pycord)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, pycord

@bot.slash_command(name="gaycheck", description="Presents series of questions to ask user if they are gay", timeout=30)
async def check(self, user: discord.Member):

```
global stripped_name

if (user.nick == None):
    stripped_name = str(user)
    name = stripped_name[:-5]
else:
    name = user.nick

field = f'''

{name}, {random.choice(question)}

'''

embed = discord.Embed(color=0xffffff).add_field(

    name = f'__Is {name} gay?__',
    value =  f'{field}',
    inline = False,

)

channel = discord.utils.get(self.guild.channels, name='stonks')
await channel.send(embed=embed, view=ButtonView(timeout=30))
```

I've tried looking around for an answer in the documentation and a lot of googling and came down to this :(. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your command should have `ctx: discord.ApplicationContext` as an argument instead of `self`. You add `self` when in a cog, which doesn't look like what you're doing. With ctx, you can do `await ctx.respond(...)`.

Here's the documentation for it:
https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/application_commands.html#discord.ApplicationContext
https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands